# Can it be created a batch to zip multiple file with similar name in one zip?

Tags: windows, zip, 7-zip

I have multiple file roms in one folder. I want to zip all files that have the first part of the name before the underscore together in 1 zip file.
For example:

```
rom_disk1.adf rom_disk2.adf in rom.zip 
rom2_disk1.adf rom2_disk2.adf rom2_disk3.adf in rom2.zip
exc. exc.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135092/discussion-on-question-by-remo-colapietro-can-it-be-created-a-batch-to-zip-multi).

Answer (score 0):

Oh the question got unlocked. So it would be something like this:

```
@echo off
if exist "%~1" (IF not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Seven=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
set "Pasta=%~1"
If exist "%~dp0list.txt" del /q "%~dp0list.txt"
pushd "%Pasta%"

for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%b in ("%%~a") do call :Zipping "%%~a" "%%~b" "%%~c"
popd
pause
exit
                                                                                       
:Zipping

for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%~3") do set P2Name=%%a
IF not Defined P1Name (
                       set P1Name=%~2
                       for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "*!P1Name!*!P2Name!*"') do >>"%~dp0list.txt" echo %%~dpnxa
                       "%Seven%" a -tzip -sdel -i@"%~dp0list.txt" "!P1Name!.zip" 1>nul 2>nul
                       IF exist "%~dp0list.txt" del /q "%~dp0list.txt"
                      )

IF /i not "%~2"=="!P1Name!" (
                             set P1Name=%~2
                             for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "*!P1Name!*!P2Name!*"') do >>"%~dp0list.txt" echo %%~dpnxa
                             "%Seven%" a -tzip -sdel -i@"%~dp0list.txt" "!P1Name!.zip" 1>nul 2>nul
                             IF exist "%~dp0list.txt" del /q "%~dp0list.txt"                                                     
                            )


goto :EOF
```

If it doesn't work try this one:

```
@echo off
if exist "%~1" (IF not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Seven=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
set "Pasta=%~1"
pushd "%Pasta%"

for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%b in ("%%~a") do (

                                                                                          IF not Defined P1Name (
                                                                                                                 set P1Name=%%b
                                                                                                                 "%Seven%" a -tzip -sdel "!P1Name!.zip" "!P1Name!*" 1>nul
                                                                                                                )
                                                                                          IF /i not "%%b"=="!P1Name!" (
                                                                                                                       set P1Name=%%b
                                                                                                                       "%Seven%" a -tzip -sdel "!P1Name!.zip" "!P1Name!*" 1>nul 
                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                      ) 

                                                                                         )
```

[image]